# How can I deal with exception handler in Visual C/C++ inline assembly?

Tags: assembly, c

I have disassembled a function in IDA Pro and I want to compile it into my project in visual c inline assembly... I'm still a newbie, so let me apologize if I don't use the right terminology...(I'm not an English native speaker) I have come up with this disassembly with IDA Pro:

```
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
push    0FFFFFFFFh
push    offset stru_xxxxx
```

and if I follow `offset stru_xxxxx`, I see this

```
stru_xxxxx   _SCOPETABLE_ENTRY <0FFFFFFFFh, 0, offset locxxxxx>
```

`offset locxxxxx` is the location of the function (`xor ebx, ebx`      Finally handler 0 for function XXXXXX)

Now, I'm aware it is a **seh exception** in C, but how can I reproduce it in inline assembly?  How can I declare `stru_xxxxx`?

Answer (score 1):

you can declare struct in c and access them in assembly

```
typedef struct _SCOPETABLE_ENTRY {
    DWORD EnclosingLevel;
    void* FilterFunc;
    void* HandlerFunc;
}ScopeTable, *PscpopeTable;
void * SomeFilt() {
    return &SomeFilt;
}
void * SomeHandler() {
    return &SomeHandler;
}
int main() {
    printf("%20s%p\n%20s%p\n",
        "Somefilt Addr = ", SomeFilt(), "SomeHandler Addr = ", SomeHandler());
    ScopeTable foo = { 0 };
    printf("Enclosing Level %x FilterFunc = %p HandlerFunc = %p\n",
        foo.EnclosingLevel, foo.FilterFunc, foo.HandlerFunc);
    __asm {
        lea ebx, foo
        mov[ebx]foo.EnclosingLevel, 1
        mov[ebx]foo.FilterFunc, offset SomeFilt
        mov[ebx]foo.HandlerFunc, offset SomeHandler
    }
    printf("Enclosing Level %x FilterFunc = %p HandlerFunc = %p\n",
        foo.EnclosingLevel, foo.FilterFunc, foo.HandlerFunc);
    return 0;
}
```

and executing this

```
    Somefilt Addr = 0006137F
 SomeHandler Addr = 00061384
Enclosing Level 0 FilterFunc = 00000000 HandlerFunc = 00000000
Enclosing Level 1 FilterFunc = 0006137F HandlerFunc = 00061384
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

SEH is not supported in inline assembly, you should use C syntax for it.